# Регулярное выражения для логина

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.
прошу помощи в написании регулярки для проверки логина при регистрации пользователя.

Параметры:

1. Логин может состоять только из букв латинского алфавита, цифр, нижнего подчеркивания, тире.
2. Логин может начинаться только с буквы или цифры.
3. Заканчиваться только буквой или цифрой.
4. в логине может быть только один дефис или одно подчеркивание. (именно или дефис или подчеркивание)

Comment: Немного не понял, дефис или подчёркивание обязательно присутствует?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Логин может начинаться только с буквы или цифры*

```
^[a-z\d]
```

> *Заканчиваться только буквой или цифрой*

```
[a-z\d]$
```

> *в логине может быть только один дефис или одно подчеркивание. (именно или дефис или подчеркивание)*

```
[a-z\d]*[_-]?[a-z\d]*
```

Шаблон в сборе:

```
~^[a-z\d][a-z\d]*[_-]?[a-z\d]*[a-z\d]$~i
```

Вместе с php будет выглядеть так:

```
$str = '0we-r9';

$patt = '~^[a-z\d][a-z\d]*[_-]?[a-z\d]*[a-z\d]$~i';
preg_match($patt, $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: благодарю за помощь

Comment: но логин к примеру: ver#stala, пропускается вашей регуляркой, а так не должно быть

Comment: @verstala обновил ответ.

Comment: спасибо, проверил, пока не нашел ошибок

Comment: Эдуард, пропустил одну проверку, логин не может состоять только из цифр. поправьте Ваш ответ пожалуйста.

Comment: @verstala в таком случае придётся пожертвовать первым или последним символом - в данный момент логин может начинаться с буквы или цифры, и заканчиваться буквой или цифрой, и это значит что логин, состоящий из двух любых цифр, вполне соответствует правилам.

Comment: @verstala если не хочется запрещать цифру в начале или в конце логина, то можно воспользоваться таким шаблоном `'~^[a-z\d][a-z\d]*(?:[a-z_-]|[_-])[a-z\d]*[a-z\d]$~i'`, но имейте ввиду, что под соответствие будут попадать такие ники: 5-5, или 3_0.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так, если дефиса или подчёркивания может и не быть:

```
/^([^\W_]|[^\W_]+[_\-]?[^\W_]+)$/
```

Если обязательно что-то из этого должно быть:

```
/^[^\W_]+[_\-][^\W_]+$/
```

Comment: `q-_q` не проходит

Comment: @teran, правильно, "в логине может быть только один дефис или одно подчеркивание. (именно или дефис или подчеркивание)"

Comment: а, точно, пардоньте :)

Comment: не проще `[^\W_][^\W_]*` записать как `[^\W_]{1,}`, нагляднее вроде ж?

Comment: @teran, если дефиса или подчёркивания может не быть, должен проходить логин из одного символа. А второй вариант сейчас исправлю, спасибо.

Comment: Второй не берет `testlogin5`

Comment: @RazGalstyan, подождите, второй вариант для логина с дефисом или подчёркиванием

Comment: че то я хрень какую то написал :) `{1,}` это тупо `+`. че то не мой день :D

Comment: @teran Я так бы не сказал, утром то помогли мне)))

Comment: Да и еще все ровно второй вариант не берет мой классный логин `testlogin5`.

Comment: @RazGalstyan ну дак то утро было, а счас день :D

Comment: @RazGalstyan вам же написали. что второй вариант для условия когда дефис или подчеркивание - обязательны (если такое требуется), в вашем логине их и нет.

Comment: @teran ах да, а я че то не увидел это))). Уже не утро а день :-D